# Looping through string splitted in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which returns a data from a column[datatype varchar2] in string format.

```
select AuditEvents.BeforeValue from  AuditEvents where condition......
```

Now , AuditEvents.BeforeValue has a mix type of data like null or "1,2,3,4,5"  or "2,3,1,4"  or "3,14" or "11:10" or "Security"  --without quotes. These "1,2,3,4,5" are eventId in another table 'EventDesc'.

AuditEvents.BeforeValue column data depends on another column, AuditEvents.EventyType which is varchar. In EventyType column, if data is "ExcludedEvents" then BeforeValue should fetch data from another table EventDesc which has eventId description. Like 1=Event1  2=Event2 etc.So in case of "1,2,3" it should fetch data as "Event1,Event2,Event3"

My query is is it possible to fetch data based on above scenario directly in oracle query rather than doing in c# side(as I'm having alot of trouble when Ui asks for searching or sorting)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes, with some trouble because not all values exist in your `events` table, nor are all of them valid.

See this example, read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  events (id, name) as
  4    (select 1, 'Event 1' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'Event 2' from dual union all
  6     select 3, 'Event 3' from dual
  7    ),
  8  auditevents (beforevalue) as
  9    (select '2,3,1'    from dual union all
 10     select 'security' from dual union all
 11     select '11:10'    from dual
 12    ),
 13  -- query you might need begins here
 14  -- split AUDITEVENTS to rows
 15  ae_split as
 16    (select beforevalue,
 17        regexp_substr(beforevalue, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) id
 18     from auditevents cross join
 19        table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 20                            connect by level <= regexp_count(beforevalue, ',') + 1
 21                           ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 22    )
 23  -- join split AUDITEVENTS with the EVENTS table
 24  select s.beforevalue, listagg(e.name, ', ') within group (order by e.id) events
 25  from ae_split s join events e on to_char(e.id) = s.id
 26  where exists (select null from events a where to_char(a.id) = s.id)
 27  group by s.beforevalue;

BEFOREVALUE EVENTS
----------- ------------------------------
2,3,1       Event 1, Event 2, Event 3

SQL>
```

Comment: but i want is the output of the 2,3,1 should not be 3 rows but single row string comma separated i.e  2,3,1 should result in single row as Event2,Event3,Event1

Comment: I edited the answer; basically, it is the LISTAGG you'd use.